# Need a simple preg_match() pattern PHP

Tags: php

The hardest thing for me in PHP, so far, is the `preg_match()` pattern. I pass an `id` variable that starts with a "n" letter or a "q" letter and has numbers after it. For example

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

echo $id;

output: n123
```

Now, I need different functions to run when a certain letter is in front of the `id` numerals.
How can I accomplish this with `preg_match()`? I've started something...:

```
$n_pattern = '/n[^0-9]/';
$q_pattern = '/q[^0-9]/';
```

But I didn't even try it out, because I'm sure that it's not correct :) 
BTW, the `id` number is between 1 int and 6 int so I'll need to match them all up. (don't know if I said it correctly... let's say the `id` can be any number between 1 and 999999).

Comment: Should an id like 'n00000009' also be considered 'ok'? Or only 'n9'?

Comment: no, the SQL does auto increment so no 000000009 is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should this regex for your match:

```
/^[qn]\d{1,6}$/
```

Which means your input can start with letters q or n followed by 1 to 6 digits.

Comment: so a separate one for "q" and a separate one for "n" would be:
/^[n]\d{1,6)$/ and 
/^[q]\d{1,6)$/?

Comment: Yes that's correct, you can simply use `/^n\d{1,6}$/` OR `/^q\d{1,6}$/` sorry it ends with `}` instead of `)`

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is just to detect the first character and validate if the second part is numeric/integer;

```
$type = $id{0}; // first character of the id (n, q)
$number = (int) substr($id, 1); // rest of the id
```

To validate if the 'type' is correct, you can use something like;

```
if (!in_array($type, array('n', 'q')) {
    // invalid type
}
```